# shiny progress bar with css

Tags: css, r, shiny, progress-bar, progress

In the following script I try to change the default Shiny progress bar with CSS:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot

    dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      n <- 10

      for (i in 1:n) {
        dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))
        incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    })

    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
   tags$style(type = 'text/css', '.shiny-progress .progress-text { color: #020202; font-size: 30px; background-color: #FF0000; }'),

   plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
   actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I try to change the color, fontsize and background color with this line:

```
tags$style(type = 'text/css', '.shiny-progress .progress-text { color: #020202; font-size: 30px; background-color: #FF0000; }'),
```

exactly following Winston Chang's advice at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/aFJTOLhld3U and consulting: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/515a67a/inst/www/shared/shiny.css#L94-L114

but whatever I try, nothing changes the progress bar. Does anyone have any idea? E.g. am I using the right css selector to 'connect' to the shiny progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom css, you have to set the option `style="old"`:

```
withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
  n <- 10
  for (i in 1:n) {
    dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))
    incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }
}, style="old")
```